# How to check if a number is palindrome in Clean

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language

I am solving this homework of clean programming language;
The problem is we have a number of five digits and we want to check whether it's an odd palindrome or not.
I am stuck at the stage of dividing the number to five separate digits and perform a comparison with the original number, for the palindrome check. With Clean I can't loop over the number and check if it remains the same from the both sides, so I am looking for an alternative solution (Some mathematical operations).

Code block:

```
isOddPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
isOddPalindrome a
| isFive a <> 5 = abort("The number should be exactly five digits...")
| (/*==> Here should be the palindrome check <==*/) && (a rem 2 <> 0) = True
| otherwise = False

isFive :: Int -> Int
isFive n
| n / 10 == 0 = 1
= 1 + isFive(n / 10)
```

My idea is to take the number, append it's digits one by one to an empty list, then perform the `reverse` method on the list and check if it's the same number or not (Palindrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying to figure out how to recursively add the digits of our number to an empty list, I did the following:

```
sepDigits :: Int [Int] -> [Int]
sepDigits n x = sepDigits (n/10) [n rem 10 : x]
```

Now I can easily check whether the reverse is equal to the initial list :) then the number is palindrome.

Comment: You could also use `fromString (toString n)` to get a `[Char]` containing the digits of `n`, and check equality on the reverse. But that may not be the intention of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer above doesn't have a stopping condition so it will result in stack overflow.

You could try this

```
numToList :: Int -> [Int]
numToList n
| n < 10 = [n]
= numToList (n/10) ++ [n rem 10]

Start = numToList 12345
```

and then like you mentioned in the answer, you can reverse it with the 'reverse' function and check if they are equal.

Comment: The stopping condition is the number of digits itself, so it will just append each digit to a "new" list, when the digits are completed the recursion will stop. There's no stack overflow. I like your approach to the problem anyways, thank you for sharing!